# Buddypress - Post to Side-Wide Activity from custom page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to post a comment to the "Site-Wide Activity" page from a custom page. I have been looking around for a solution but nothing works.

How can I post an image and comment using a custom basic script like the one below?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submitToActivity"])) {

    $arrayPost = [$_POST["imgUrlString"],$_POST["comment-user"] ];

    add_post_type_support( $arrayPost, 'buddypress-activity' );

    echo "$UserName Posted a new comment";

}

?>

<form method="post" name="sendToActivity">
<label>Url Img</label>
<input type="text" id="imgUrlString" name="imgUrlString" />

<label>Comment</label>
<input type="text" id="comment-user" name="comment-user" />

<input type="submit" name="submitToActivity" id="submitToActivity">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`add_post_type_support()` doesn't save anything, it just declares (in this case) the support of storing some data (new post of that post type) in BuddyPress activity feed. More info about BuddyPress support [here](https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/post-types-activities/). You will need to read the doc about this function [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) as well, as you are adding support incorrectly.

It seems, that you need to take a look at `bp_activity_add($args);`, here is [the doc.](https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/function-examples/bp_activity_add/)